# How can you get a url for every piece of data?

Tags: firebase

I am building an IM platform based on Firebase and I would like that every user got an address that directed them to the chat room.

http://chatt3r.sitecloud.cytanium.com/

Comment: Just create a record whenever you create a new user and associate it with an ID or a short (tiny) URL.  Then have your page read the ID from the URL.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: There is no registration or longing system you just go to the page and you are generated a url.

Comment: You can create an insert statement on page load, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>

    <script>
        var hash; // global incase needed elsewhere

        $(function() {
            hash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");;
            myRootRef = new Firebase("http://xxxx.firebaseio.com");

            var postingRef;

            if (hash) {
                // user has been given a hashed URL from their friend, so sets firebase root to that place
                console.log(hash);

                postingRef = new Firebase("http://xxxx.firebaseio.com/chatrooms/" + hash);
            } else {
                // there is no hash, so the user is looking to share a URL for a new room
                console.log("no hash");

                postingRef = new Firebase("http://xxxx.firebaseio.com/chatrooms/");
                // push for a unique ID for the chatroom
                postingRef = postingRef.push();
                // exploit this unique ID to provide a unique ID host for you app
                window.location.hash = postingRef.toString().slice(34);
            }

            // listener
            // will pull all old messages up once bound
            postingRef.on("child_added", function(data) {
                console.log(data.val().user + ": " + data.val().message);
            });
            // later:
            postingRef.push({"message": "etc", "user": "Jimmybobjimbobjimbobjim"});
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

That's working for me locally.  You need to change xxxx to whatever URL yours is at, and add on however many characters that first part is at the .slice() bit.

Comment: No problem, tell me if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Hashes.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to share a URL that will allow anyone who clicks on the URL to log onto the same chatroom.

I did this for a Firebase application I made once.  The first thing you need to be doing is using the `.push()` [method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html).   Push the room to Firebase, then use the `toString()` method to get the URL of the push.  Some quick JS string manipulation - `window.location.hash = pushRef.toString().slice(x)` - where 'x' is whatever place you want to snip the URL at.  `window.location.hash` will set the hash for you.  Add the hash to the sharing URL, and then for the next step:

You will want a hash listener to check if there is already a hash when you open the page, so `$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {UpdateHash()})` goes into a doc.ready function, and then...

```
function UpdateHash() {
    global_windowHash = window.hash.replace("#", "");
    // to assign the hash to a global hash variable
    if (global_windowHash) {
        // if there was already a hash
        chatRef = new Firebase("[Your Firebase URL here]" + "/chatrooms/" + global_windowHash);
        // chatRef is the global that you append the chat data to, and listen from.
    } else {
        // there wasn't a hash, so you can auto-create a new one here, in which case:
        chatRef = new Firebase("[Your Firebase URL here]" + "/chatrooms/");
        chatRef = chatRef.push();
        window.location.hash = chatRef.toString().slice(x);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps (and works :P ).  If there are any questions or problems, then just ask!

Comment: Can you please send me an example with HTML.

Comment: I'll post one later - I don't have time right now, sorry - you can e-mail me if you want me to send it directly :)

Comment: This is like syncing data between clients with FireBase.