# Javascript : Get domain name

Tags: javascript, firebase, dns

I bought two domain name on freenom.com and I have an app on Firebase.

I am trying to know which domain as been typed to land on my page.

I tried :

```
location.hostname
document.location
document.location.href
```

But they all return the Firebase url. Does anyone knows how I could get it?

Edit: I suspect that my problem comes from Firebase or Freename, could they block me from getting the domain name ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract the hostname portion of a URL in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/how-to-extract-the-hostname-portion-of-a-url-in-javascript)

Comment: @Antoine: as you can see both the comment and first answer point to using  `location.hostname`. If that doesn't work, please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Keep in mind that many thousands of web sites depend on using `location.hostname`, so your problem is likely quite specific to what you are doing. For example: if you can share the URL where you are testing, we could look at the same thing you see.

Comment: I added a link in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the domain like this. It ain't clean, but it works

```
  function getDomain() {
    var domain = window.location.hostname;
    var parts = domain.split('.').reverse();
    var cnt = parts.length;
    if (cnt >= 3) {
      if (parts[1].match(/^(com|edu|gov|net|mil|org|nom|co|name|io|info|biz)$/i)) {
          return parts[2] + '.' + parts[1] + '.' + parts[0];
      }
    }
    return parts[1] + '.' + parts[0];
  }
```

Comment: It does not work for me. Try this [link](http://hotpotato.ml/) to see what my problem is.

Comment: no, it doesn't work because your code is being called from an iframe. So the iframe is sourced from w3 schools so it's hostname is w3 schools. Iframes tend to be tricky... The function works, it just's calling itself from a different source.

Answer (score 0):

```js
domainName = window.location.hostname.split('.')[0]; //ie... google
console.log(domainName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: In your case with Firebase... Reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004008/how-can-you-get-a-url-for-every-piece-of-data may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ->

```
window.location.hostname
```